# Splash Screen Video is not playing

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, splash-screen

I'm using video for splash screen but it is not playing,it shows black screen,Here is my code

```
  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
  NSString* moviePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"hello" ofType:@"mp4"];
  NSURL* movieURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:moviePath];

  playerCtrl =  [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];
  playerCtrl.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeFill;
  playerCtrl.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
  playerCtrl.view.autoresizingMask =UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;


 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish)
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:nil];
 [self.window addSubview:playerCtrl.view];
 [playerCtrl play];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try setting the player view frame to the window bounds?

Comment: can you please elaborate

Comment: Your player view has a frame of CGRectZero, so you only see the window. `playerCtrl.frame = self.window.bounds` should solve the issue

Comment: That's because MPMovieScalingModeFill will not preserve video proportions and simply stretch it to fill the view. You can either use MPMovieScalingModeAspectFit or MPMovieScalingModeAspectFill, depending on what you're trying to achieve